# Need to remove apostrophe from json collection in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.5

I am new to python code.

Currently I am able to create json from key value pair. 
Now jsonRow have few fields like below

**jsonRow = json.dumps(row)**

```
{"abc": "SDT", "RIC": "SFOpmM5", "currency": "TN", "source": "xyz", "desc": "FUEL OIL JUN15", "maturityDate": "02-Jun-2015", "symbol": "1283968", "contractMultiplier": "100.000000", "securityType": "ijk"}
```

I keep getting json like above with different values.

I wanted to add all the json into some collection
Currently I am using below variable to have all the json. I dont know this is correct or not

**top = []**

Now I am using **top.append(jsonRow)** and it is adding all into this variable.

Problem is, it is adding everything with **' '** It is not a collection of json. I tried list also but same issue. If I pass this to REST service as a collection of json, it is giving error **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required,**

Output

```
['{"abc": "SDT", "RIC": "SFOpmM5", "currency": "TN", "source": "xyz", "desc": "FUEL OIL JUN15", "maturityDate": "02-Jun-2015", "symbol": "1283968", "contractMultiplier": "100.000000", "securityType": "ijk"}','{"abc": "SDT", "RIC": "SFOpmM5", "currency": "TN", "source": "xyz", "desc": "FUEL OIL JUN15", "maturityDate": "02-Jun-2015", "symbol": "1283968", "contractMultiplier": "100.000000", "securityType": "ijk"}']
```

I dont want `['{}','{}','{}']` 
I want `[{},{},{}]` so that I can pass to my REST call

Comment: Why not directly append `top.append(row)` you are getting a json result

Comment: It will add as  `{'abc':'SDT'}` not `{"abc":"SDT"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the JSON into a list, but the original dictionary, and *then* convert to JSON:

```
>>> row  # the original dict
{'abc': 'SDT',
 'RIC': 'SFOpmM5',
 'securityType': 'ijk',
 'currency': 'TN',
 'contractMultiplier': '100.000000',
 'maturityDate': '02-Jun-2015',
 'symbol': '1283968',
 'source': 'xyz',
 'desc': 'FUEL OIL JUN15'}
>>> top = [row]  # possibly more entries, or use `append`
>>> json.dumps(top)
'[{"abc": "SDT", "RIC": "SFOpmM5", "securityType": "ijk", "currency": "TN", "contractMultiplier": "100.000000", "maturityDate": "02-Jun-2015", "symbol": "1283968", "source": "xyz", "desc": "FUEL OIL JUN15"}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['{**"abc": "SDT", "RIC": "SFOpmM5", "currency": "TN", "source": "xyz", "desc": "FUEL OIL JUN15", "maturityDate": "02-Jun-2015", "symbol": "1283968", "contractMultiplier": "100.000000", "securityType": "ijk"**}','{**"abc": "SDT", "RIC": "SFOpmM5", "currency": "TN", "source": "xyz", "desc": "FUEL OIL JUN15", "maturityDate": "02-Jun-2015", "symbol": "1283968", "contractMultiplier": "100.000000", "securityType": "ijk"**}']
import json
json_ = [json.loads(val.replace("**",'')) for val in data]
print(json_)
>>>[{'RIC': 'SFOpmM5',
  'abc': 'SDT',
  'contractMultiplier': '100.000000',
  'currency': 'TN',
  'desc': 'FUEL OIL JUN15',
  'maturityDate': '02-Jun-2015',
  'securityType': 'ijk',
  'source': 'xyz',
  'symbol': '1283968'},
 {'RIC': 'SFOpmM5',
  'abc': 'SDT',
  'contractMultiplier': '100.000000',
  'currency': 'TN',
  'desc': 'FUEL OIL JUN15',
  'maturityDate': '02-Jun-2015',
  'securityType': 'ijk',
  'source': 'xyz',
  'symbol': '1283968'}]
```

Comment: I think those `**` were inserted by OP to highlight the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a list of strings, then the following solution will work:

```
for i, item in enumerate(listofitems):
    listofitems[i] = item.strip('"')
```

It goes through every element in the list and removes quote sign from it. Then the stripped string is assigned to the proper index of the list.